# Code Library for ILI9341 TFT Display 16 bit interface with STM32F401

Tags: stm32f4, hal, stm32cubeide

I have realized that my TFT module that incorporates an **ILI9341** controller, is only avaliable for **16bit interface** (probably configured by hardware). So I tried to use the HAL library provided by ardnew https://github.com/ardnew/ILI9341-STM32-HAL, but is only compatible with SPI interface. I want to know if there is some code for this config of microcontroller and TFT module.

Also I dont know if the 16bit parallel interface is I or II, because there is no information about this. The module board have a description "TFT_320QDT_9341".

The actual microcontroller im using is **STM32F401RE**, sadly this micro doesnt have FSMC peripheal avaliable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the interface you connect to MCU with? Reference manual has neither FSMC nor LTDC, in fact, it doesn't have any dedicated screen driving peripheral at all. So what do you want to drive screen with if not SPI?

Comment: My ILI9341 embeded module doesnt have the pins avaliable por spi conection, in fact, by hardware is configured the pins that controll de interface of communication between LCD and MCU to use it as 16bit parallel interface. So that is the issue, SPI libraries are avaliable on ardnew repository, but no for parallel.

Comment: I will repeat my question, which you didn't answer: what peripheral inside MCU is supposed to drive the LCD? Your MCU does NOT have a peripheral that can drive parallel display.